# Am I on the right track..finding matches between two tables(SQL)

Tags: sql

I'm a SQL noob and I'm wondering if someone could give me
some help with the folowing problem:
So I have two tables "Schools" and "Teachers".
the "search_key" column of the "Schools" table is one big string that
combines teachers name and other elements (example: `"ENGLISH | JANE |  [90, 56]`)
So what I'm trying to do is match the string  from the column "name"
of the "teachers" table with that previous one, getting the cells that have a match.

```
SELECT * FROM(

SELECT substr(a.search_key, 6, instr(a.search_key, '|'))

  FROM schools a

  ) JOIN teachers s ON a.search_key = s.search_key
```

This is what Ive been trying to do, substring and try and match, but no luck so far.
Any ideas?

Comment: can you share the layout of the two tables? If you can supply a couple sample rows of data that would also be beneficial

Comment: There's the Teacher Table: It has an id, teacher_name and subject
Also a School Table that has a column that receives several values, including the teacher's name. I need to isolate the teachers name in that string so I can find matches with that same name on the Teacher's table:

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it would be more complicated than:

```
SELECT *
FROM schools s
INNER JOIN teachers t ON t.teacher_name LIKE '%' + s.search_key + '%'
```

Comment: other than you would get hits on names that are partials of another name. But this simple approach is my preference.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going -

```
WITH SCHOOLS AS (
    SELECT
        'ENGLISH | JANE | [90,56]' AS SEARCH_KEY
    FROM
        DUAL
),TEACHER AS (
    SELECT
        'JANE' AS NAME
    FROM
        DUAL
) SELECT
    S.SEARCH_KEY
FROM
    SCHOOLS S,
    TEACHER T
WHERE
    S.SEARCH_KEY LIKE '%' || T.NAME || '%';
```

> Output -

```
SEARCH_KEY
ENGLISH | JANE | [90, 56]
```

Another approach would be -

```
WITH SCHOOLS AS (
    SELECT
        'ENGLISH | JANE | [90,56]' AS SEARCH_KEY
    FROM
        DUAL
),TEACHER AS (
    SELECT
        'JANE' AS NAME
    FROM
        DUAL
) SELECT
    S.SEARCH_KEY
FROM
    SCHOOLS S,
    TEACHER T
WHERE
      TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(S.SEARCH_KEY,'(\S*)(\W)',1,3)) = T.NAME;
```

This works if the name is always the 2nd field value in the SEARCH_KEY field de-limited by |

Comment: So basicly you pass a name and it gives you back the search_key right?
Don't I need a Join to make sure I get all the cases where there is the same name? (Again, I'm a total newbie, just asking a question to learn :) )

Comment: Check the 2nd query which joins the 2 tables. This also isolates the teacher name from the field in school table based on the assumptions mentioned.